# How to select from one column or the other based on NULL values in R?

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to set up an if else statement that allows me to create a third column based on information from two other columns. Here is a sample dataset.

```
df <- data.frame(RequestTimeSecs1 = c(0, 44, 65, "N/A", 100), RequestTimeSecs2 = c(0,46, 55, 77, 112))
```

I want to create a third column called "RequestTimeSecs" which takes values from ReqeustTimeSecs1 unless RequestTimeSecs1 has N/A values. In that case, I want to select from RequestTimeSecs2 column.

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
df$RequestTimeSecs <- ifelse((df$RequestTimeSecs1 != "N/A"), df$RequestTimeSecs1, df$RequestTimeSecs2)
```

When I do this, I am getting the following results

| RequestTimeSecs1 | RequestTimeSec2 | RequestTimeSecs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 44 | 46 | 3 |
| 65 | 55 | 4 |
| N/A | 77 | 77 |
| 100 | 112 | 2 |

So in RequestTimeSecs, I got the desired input for N/A value, it should be 77 however, I don't know where the rest of the row numbers are coming for. In RequestTimeSecs, I want the following numbers c(0,44,65,77,100).

Please let me know where I am messing up in setting up the if else statement

Comment: When I run your code I get the expected result, i.e. 0, 44, 65, 77, 100 in the RequestTimeSecs. Is there anything else going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `coalesce` after converting the first column to `numeric`.  Below, we replaced the `"N/A"` to `NA`, convert to `numeric` and used `coalesce` so that if there is any NA on the 'TimeSecs1', it will be replaced by the corresponding element of 'TimeSecs2'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(RequestTimeSecs = coalesce(as.numeric(na_if(RequestTimeSecs1, 
        "N/A")), RequestTimeSecs2))
```

-output

```
df1
#    RequestTimeSecs1 RequestTimeSecs2 RequestTimeSecs
#1                0                0               0
#2               44               46              44
#3               65               55              65
#4              N/A               77              77
#5              100              112             100
```

---

NOTE: From `R 4.0`, by default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  So, if the R version is old, there is a chance that the column would be `factor` class.  In that case we can either do

```
df$RequestTimeSecs <- as.character(df$RequestTimeSecs)
```

before running the above code or use

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! However, when I run this, the RequestTimeSecs column is  type logic. Can I convert that to numeric so I can have the numbers?

Comment: @Sanam this i run based on the example you showed.  Is the first column character class and second numeric in your example

Comment: @Sanam I think your column may be factor.  Can you try the update

Comment: yes, I just converted my column from factor to character and now it works. Thanks for your help